# How to stop focus from moving between EditText fields on ENTER

Tags: android

I'm making a shopping cart app that dynamically generates rows as items get added. For each item row, an EditText field is used for the item quantity so that quantities can be modified. Since the quantities need to be integers for calculations, I'm using a parseInt to convert the text grabbed from an altered EditText and trapping out any NFEs in case the input was bad.

When the input is good, everything works fine. When the input is bad, the EditText is set back to its prior value (as desired) but if there is another (dynamically-generated) row below it, the focus shifts to the EditText in that lower row. The desired behavior is for the focus to remain in the EditText that the user wants to change.

Regarding what happens to focus on a successful change -- the virtual keyboard closes on success and nothing keeps focus. In that try/catch block I try to hide the keyboard, but that doesn't help ... it stays open on shifting to the lower field.

Here's an image if it helps to visualize:
[before and after hitting `ENTER`](http://www.thefineline.org/wcc/edittext_image.png)

I've read other posts about using requestFocus() and I've used it here but it doesn't seem to have any effect -- maybe due to all this being generated on the fly? I've also seen posts saying that dynamically generated views don't have any IDs you can grab for being a bit more specific in identifying what should get the focus, but perhaps I'm not understanding it in this context.

So, how do I keep the focus in the field the user wants to edit after handling the NFE and resetting the value of that field?

Here's the specific code that catches that NFE:

```
try {
    quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantityCell.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a valid number",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(quantityView.getWindowToken(), 0);
    quantityCell.setText("" + savedQuantity);
    quantityCell.requestFocus();

    return false;
}
```

... and here is all the code that goes into generating that EditText field on the fly:

```
// create quantity edittext and add to row
final EditText quantityView = new EditText(this);
quantityView.setLayoutParams(cellParams);
quantityView.setSingleLine();
quantityView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
quantityView.setText("" + theQuantity);
quantityView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // capture old value of quantity before changing it
        EditText et = (EditText)v;
        savedQuantity = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
        return false;
    }
});
quantityView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                int quantity;
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                TableRow theRow = (TableRow) v.getParent();
                TextView nameCell = (TextView) theRow.getChildAt(0);
                String name = nameCell.getText().toString();
                EditText quantityCell = (EditText) theRow.getChildAt(1);
                try {
                    quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantityCell.getText().toString());
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a valid number",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(quantityView.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    quantityCell.setText("" + savedQuantity);
                    quantityCell.requestFocus();

                    return false;
                }
                TextView unitCell = (TextView) theRow.getChildAt(2);
                double unit = Double.parseDouble(unitCell.getText().toString().substring(1));
                TextView totalCell = (TextView) theRow.getChildAt(3);
                double total = Double.parseDouble(totalCell.getText().toString().substring(1));

                totalPrice -= total;
                totalQuantity -= quantity;
                cartDB.changeQuantity(name, quantity, unit);
                removeAllRows();
                writeOrderTable();

                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(quantityView.getWindowToken(), 0);
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }
});
// set length of edittext line
productRow.addView(quantityView);
```

EDIT:
Looking at the code in that catch clause, I'm guessing that the line to hide the virtual keyboard wouldn't do much if the desired field retained any focus in the first place, so maybe I should remove it. The reason it's there is that I tried doing that (hiding the virtual keyboard) to just remove any focus at all and that approach did not work. The field below still grabbed focus and the keyboard remained open.

ANOTHER EDIT:
This does not happen with a physical keyboard -- at least when using by computer keyboard with a Genymotion virtual device (can't use a built-in AVD, I have an AMD cpu). When the same simulator is set to use a virtual keyboard, the problem appears.

FINAL EDIT:
I altered the try/catch block to this and it works as desired. Changes are in the catch clause:

```
try {
    quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantityCell.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a valid number",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    quantity = savedQuantity;
}
```

Some code later in the larger block above winds up handling resetting the field when the user inputs bad data. I'm guessing the cause of what was happening was me trying to restore the old value with that setText() method in the old code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw a possible answer here: http://imax-live.blogspot.hk/2012/12/prevent-enter-key-on-edittext-as-multi.html

The idea is to override the keyborad input so that the user cannot use the normal function of the "enter" key

Btw, you can set **android:inputType="number"** in xml so that only numbers can be entered into the edit text field

```
class MyTextView extends EditText
{
...
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) 
        {
            // Just ignore the [Enter] key
            return true;
        }
        // Handle all other keys in the default way
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: After translating that page, from what I could see in the docs about using that onKeyDown trap was that it isn't reliable with virtual keyboards and that most do not implement it for catching `ENTER`.

This is all being generated with no XML for that attribute but it's a great idea. I added this line:

    quantityView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

and it does limit the user to entering numbers, but an empty value can still be submitted and the focus still moves ... so ALMOST a solution.

Comment: Going to mark this as answered ... figured out what was happening thanks to your post, @VoidExplorer